# Why should I care about ROM size when buying a new 'phone?

Tags: rom

RAM is clear enough, but why so many different ROM sizes & how much does a basic user need?

Basic == 'phone calls/WhatsApp/SMS/email/light browser use - no games, streaming, videos, music,

Comment: That mainly depends on how many attachments you receive e.g. via WhatsApp and email and if you keep them all. If you don't store everything or e.g. use IMAP for email (server stores everything, client just keep temporary copies) the you may work happily with an 32GB or even 16GB flash device. BTW: ROM means "read-only memory" - I think you mean flash memory, because a read-only memory would be of no use to you...

Comment: Hmm, apparently what's called "ROM" is actually the storage capacity (equivalent to harddisk), though I believe it's actually a misnomer since it's not "read-only memory" (as it can be writable).

Comment: @Robert I actually meant ROM. I can understand why more RAM is better, but am not so sure about ROM

Comment: Please explain what's your understanding of word "ROM" is in the context of Android phones. Are you talking about the internal flash storage (which is like 32GB, 64GB and so on)? Or are you referring to the custom operating systems which are developed by community for a device (wrongly called ROMs because they are written to `/system`, `/vendor` partitions which aren't writable for user data unlike `/data` partition)? Technically speaking there's no ROM on Android devices except some tiny part (usually a few KBs) embedded with SoCs which includes Boot-ROM (or its equivalent) like BIOS on a PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2 GB RAM or 3 GB RAM, does it really matter?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155659/2-gb-ram-or-3-gb-ram-does-it-really-matter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a prior post indicates you use a
**Ulefone Armor X3**

A quick search brings up:

[https://www.amazon.com/Smartphone-Ulefone-Armor-Waterproof-Shockproof/dp/B07VL28Y84](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VL28Y84)

And in the description reads:

> 2GB RAM + 32GB ROM

This is an error in the description. It should read

> 2GB RAM + 32GB Flash storage

That Flash storage is the same as a hard drive and will contain the OS and apps/data/pictures/videos that you are using.